# Yarn install Lerna monorepo directory with local dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monorepo, lerna, yarnpkg-v2

I have a monorepo that has 20 visual components built using Lerna. This component library is being used by another app repo and is included in it's package.json

I'm pulling in a single component from the component library into the app using a Yarn 2+ feature in package.json:

```
  "@author/component-a": "git+ssh://git@github.server.com:Author/component-lib.git#head=feature/updated-component&workspace=@author/component-a",
```

We want to push to a branch on Github rather having to publish to npmjs every time we need a change in the app. This reason we want to take this approach (rather than something like `yarn link`) is because we have a staging environment that we want to build with the changes in the branch.

The component library file structure looks like:

```
packages
  component-a
    package.json
  component-b
    package.json
package.json
```

Where `packages/component-a/package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "@author/component-a",
  "version": "1.1.0-alpha.1",
  "description": "Component A",
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@author/component-b": "1.1.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

and `packages/component-b/package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "@author/component-b",
  "version": "1.1.0-alpha.1",
  "description": "Component B",
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

I've been trying ways to get the build to refer to the local files rather than the ones published on NPMjs:

`packages/component-a/package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@author/component-b": "file:../component-b"
  }
```

Which works fine locally (building in the component library, but downstream building in the app, via a branch it breaks.

Question: How can I get a downstream app to pull in other components defined defined in the same repo from a monorepo without publishing the packages (to NPMjs) and working only via a branch.

Comment: Have you considered using the `portal:` protocol? `portal:/path/to/dependency`

Comment: I've done similar implementation using [pnpm workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) and Vite [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode), take a look at my repo [vue3-pnpm-workspace](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace), it might be helpful